# Problem with writing into txt file on my server from a Java program

Tags: java, io, ftp

I'm having this problem when trying to write into a txt file on my server from a Java program. Even though it writes the text, it writes some strange chars in front of it. My code looks like this:

```
    URL urlOutput = new URL("ftp://username:password@ftp.matsworld.io");
    URLConnection urlc = urlOutput.openConnection();
    OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
    OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
    ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
    output.writeObject("Hello world!");
    output.close();
    buffer.close();
    os.close();
```

And this is what appears in the txt file:

> ¨ŪtKVHello world!

Thanks for help!

Comment: Don't use `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` is used for object serialization. The part preceding `"Hello world!"` is the "bookkeeping" information saved by the object output stream for the object input stream to figure out what kind of object is being restored.

Use `PrintStream` for outputting textual information:

```
URL urlOutput = new URL("ftp://username:password@ftp.matsworld.io");
URLConnection urlc = urlOutput.openConnection();
OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(buffer);
output.writeLine("Hello world!");
output.close();
buffer.close();
os.close();
```